# How to rename Azure ARM VNET

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-network

I have an existing ARM VNET that I would like to rename, how can this be accomplished?  Renaming does not seem to be possible from within the Azure portal, and I haven't discovered any PowerShell solutions either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot rename a VNet in Azure. In fact, I can't think of a single resource you can rename after you created it

Comment: @woogy they all do have GUID's, but for some reason they are not renamable

Comment: well, the idea makes sense, if you look at the ARM model, like a resources name is its unique identifier, say `https://portal.azure.com/#resource/subscriptions/subGUID/resourceGroups/rgName/overview`, so renaming it could cause all kinds of bad consequences; Why they done it this way, I'm not sure, probably its more user friendly??

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a template for this it's much easier otherwise it's progressively more difficult.  If you have a template already, just change the parameters/fields and redeploy.  Azure ARMs are "differential deployments" so you'll only change the fields that are different and you won't "lose"  the rest of your infrastructure under that VNET.  I'm willing to bet that -Name- is one of the fields you can change because I've changed storage types (without losing data) after I've deployed before and that seems like a harder change.  I can't test it right now, but I will later and follow up.

If you don't already have a template.  You may have some options here too, but they're all harder.  Worst case:  you may have to export a lot of ARM Templates for ALL of your VNET dependent resources and "stitch" them together.  To export the ARM template - from the Azure Portal:  click on resource, click on export template, download the ARM.  Change what you need in a text editor of some sort -- could be NotePad if you're familiar with ARMs and then redeploy.

If you choose option #2, make sure you test it first.  IDK what the results would be for dependent resources if you manage to change the VNET name without have them saved off as additional ARMs.